# Precalculus Question about Finding Half life of Carbon

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Carbon-14 decays at a rate of 0.0121% per year. Find the half life of carbon-14.

Would I set the equation equal to 1/2? And for the rate, would it be 0.0121 or 1.21 since it is expressed as a percentage in the problem? Also, I googled the actual half life and it is 5,730, but I got 57 years.

Comment: I have undeleted your question. It appears that you deleted your question immediately after receiving an answer. This is unkind to your answerers and suggests that you are attempting to hide that you're receiving help. Whatever the reason, **Don't do that.**

Comment: @davidlowryduda Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 1):

For a radionuclide with a half-life of $T$, initial number of undecayed nuclei being $N_0$ the number of undecayed nuclei at time $t$, $N(t)$ is given by:

$N(t) = N_0(\frac 12)^{\frac tT}$

So in your case, $t=1$ and $N(1) = \frac{100-0.0121}{100} N_0$, so you get:

$(\frac 12)^{\frac 1T}= \frac{100-0.0121}{100}$

You can solve this by taking logs (doesn't matter which base as long as you use the same base) of both sides to find the value of $T$ in years.

Taking natural logs of both sides,

$\frac 1T \ln \frac 12= \ln \frac{100-0.0121}{100}$

$T \approx 5730$

So the half-life is approximately $5730$ years.

I rounded off the value based on the likely precision of the given value for the percentage change (three significant figures).